# Change letters alphabetically in a for loop to print all tokens

Tags: batch-file

I have a file (MyFile.txt) with a string like this, for example:

var1,var2,asds,123,var6

This file is generated automatically, and I don't know how many words it will have.

I make a for to print all words, one in each line. And process them one by one

```
for /f "tokens=1-30 delims=," %%a in (MyFile.txt) do call Process.bat %%a
```

In Process.bat I have `ping %1` for example.

This only processes the first token. My problem is, I need to process all tokens, but I need to do it automatically, is there a way to loop over all existing tokens?

In my example: var1,var2,asds,123,var6 it would be: `do call Process.bat %%a`, then `%%b`, then `%%c`, then `%%d` and `%%e`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work even if you have various line in `Myfile.txt`

```
@echo off&cls

for /f "delims=" %%a in (MyFile.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do call Process.bat %%b
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
set /p var=<MyFile.txt
set var="%var%"
for %%a in ("%var:,=" "%) do call Process.bat %%a
```

That Should work.

Mona

Comment: You don't need the "%var:,=" "%`` substitution  the `,` is a delimiters to.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine `for` to read all your lines and `call` to parse the vars in the line

try this to get you started

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f  %%a  in (file.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set line=!line:,= !
  call :parms !line!
)  
goto :eof

:parms
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
echo ping %1
shift
goto :parms

goto :eof
```